# On Click Display Issue

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div id="div4">
   <button id="14" class="b1">Bat</button>
   <button id="15" class="b1">Bowl</button>
</div>

<div id="div3">
<p id="id4"></p><!-- score -->
<p id="id5"></p><!-- balls -->
</div>
<div id="div1">
    <button id="id7" class="c1">Defence</button>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("id14").onclick=function(){
     document.getElementById("div4").style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("div3").style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("div1").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

I have set the `display` property of `div1`, `div3` to `none` and the `display` property of `div4` to `block` in css, when I click on bat, I want `div1`, `div3` to appear and div 4 to dissapear.
When I run the above code its not working.

Comment: It looks like your button's id is 14, not "id14".

Comment: Like @NineToeNerd said, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/uajLx8ue/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="div4">
   <button id="14" class="b1">Bat</button>
   <button id="15" class="b1">Bowl</button>
</div>

<div id="div3">
<p id="id4">p id4</p>
<p id="id5">p id5</p>
</div>
<div id="div1">
    <button id="id7" class="c1">Defence</button>
</div>
<script>
var ct = 0;    
document.getElementById("14").onclick=function(){
     console.log('id 14 clicked');
     document.getElementById("div4").style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("div3").style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("div1").style.display="block";

}
</script>
```

I recommand to use `console.log();` for testing purpose it helps to do debuging

Eg: in above code console will show "id 14 clicked", when user click on Bat.

I have noticed in your code you are using wrong id names: like `id14` and `14`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your selector from `id14` to `14` as in below code.

```
<div id="div4">
   <button id="14" class="b1">Bat</button>
   <button id="15" class="b1">Bowl</button>
</div>

<div id="div3">
<p id="id4"></p><!-- score -->
<p id="id5"></p><!-- balls -->
</div>
<div id="div1">
    <button id="id7" class="c1">Defence</button>
</div>
<script>  
document.getElementById("14").onclick=function(){

     document.getElementById("div4").style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("div3").style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("div1").style.display="block";

}
</script>
```

Comment: @Sri Harsha : Please let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @SriHarsha Please upvote it if it really helped.. So that it help other viewers..

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is that you did not define the onclick trigger when creating your buttons and have not defined your function to get your elements. Here's a basic example of a button with the onclick call, and the function it's calling.

courtesy of w3schools.com, hope this leads to a solution for you.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is not the issue. There are many ways to invoke javascript functions.